Difference-in-differences or difference-in-difference-in-differences using a Randomized control trial
For an academic project I have been given a data set on a Randomized Control Trial. I need to use this dataset to derive the treatment effects of a ‘Crop harvestor’ technology.
Data - The data is on 700 farm households for three waves (2019, 2020 and 2022) at the plot level. So, there are approximately 3500 observations. The data reports demographic information, plot characteristics, and outcomes such as crop yields, costs etc.
A Randomized control trial (RCT) was conducted on these households, where the treatment was ‘technical demonstrations’ of the benefits of harvesting and post-harvest technologies. This included demonstrations on the benefits of ‘crop harvestor’. The RTCs were conducted post collection of the data in the first wave. There were a total of 2 ‘technical demonstrations’ in 2020 and 2021. Post these demonstrations some of the treated sample adopted the ‘Crop harvestor’ and some did not.
Sample selection - These housheolds are located within villages (41 villages), located within higher geographical units called Halqa (4 in total), located within higher geographical units called tehsils (2 in total). Out of the 4 Halqa 2 are treated and 2 are control. Both tehsils have treated and control Halqa
The study follows a Cluster Randomized Control Trial (CRCT) design.
In the first stage, the tehsils were purposively selected within each target district.
In each selected tehsil, two Halqas were chosen using criteria of access to metaled roads adequate for the movement of crop harvesters to the villages.
For the selection of Villages, within each selected halqa, some villages in similar geographic proximity were selected using access to a road for transportation of machinery as a criterion.
After listing the farmers using complete enumeration, out of the two selected halqas, one was randomly assigned to the treatment group.
I have two questions.

Based on the data that I have, is a difference in difference (DID) appropriate or a ANOVA?
My task with this data is to find the treatment effects of the ‘crop harvestor’. However the 'technical demonstration' include trainings on several harvesting technologies including the 'crop harvestor'. Based on some reading of the literature, I wonder if I need to use a triple difference (difference – in – difference – in differences) approach. Where a DID will give me the ‘treatment effects’ of the 'technical demonstrations' and a DDD will differentiate the treatment effects of the technical demonstrations by adoption of the ‘crop harvestor'.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thank you

